# Load Behavior 3 Excel add-in gets loaded after opening of file, when launched via command line on a slow machine

Tags: excel, com, vsto

I have created an Excel add-in which needs to be loaded at application startup. LoadBehavior value is 3 for the add-in.

I need to handle WorkbookOpen event for excel.

When Excel is launched using command line with file path as parameter on slow machine the add-in gets loaded after opening of document.

But on normal machine the add-in gets loaded before opening of document.

Comment: So handle already opened documents in your add-in's `Workbook_Open`?

Comment: By FileOpen event I meant WorkbookOpen event. I need to do some handling on this event but since add-in is getting loaded after opening of workbook I miss this event and hence not being able to perform the intended operation.

Comment: So perform that operation later, from your add-in's `Workbook_Open`?

Comment: When excel is launched from command prompt with file path as parameter i.e.  PathToExcel\Excel.exe "PathToFile\File.xlsx", in this case the excel file gets opened completely after this the add-in gets loaded so the WorkBook_Open event for File.xlsx is missed. This is happening only on slow machine. On normal machine the add-in gets loaded first and then the xlsx file is opened hence I receive the Workbook_Open event.

Comment: So perform that operation later, from your add-in's `Workbook_Open`, in addition to the application-level `Workbook_Open`?

Comment: I think what @GSerg is trying to say that you should handle the workbooks that are already open when your add-in loads. I couldn't find the method name (I work on Word, not Excel, and on document-level add-ins), but I suspect it's `ThisAddIn_Startup` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Used this workaround. But I wanted to know if this is default behavior of Excel when launched via command line with file as parameter. Even if the add-in is marked to load on startup its gets delayed load.